# Java - How can I add an object to a list of another object

Tags: java

I have an Class called Process and a Class Called Event. Process has a list of Events as one of its attributes. I am reading a file and populating the Process attributes and the Event attributes but when I try to add the Event to the events list of the Process object I get NullPointerException. I have more experience in C# but I have to do this in Java.
This is what a line in the file looks like:

```
0 1 CPU 10 IO 3 CPU 50 IO 3 CPU 10
```

These are the classes:

```
public class Process {

int arrivalTime;
int priority;
LinkedList<Event> events;
}
```

Event.java,

```
public class Event {
String type;
int duration;
}
```

FCFS.java,

```
public class FCFS{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Process> readyQueue = new LinkedList<Process>();

    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] arr = line.split(" ");

            Process process = new Process();

            process.arrivalTime = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            process.priority = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);

            for(int i = 2; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {

                Event event = new Event();
                event.type = arr[i];
                event.duration = Integer.parseInt(arr[i+1]);
                process.events.add(event);

            }

            readyQueue.add(process);
            // read next line
            line = reader.readLine();

        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is due to not initializing the events. can you try doing the below

```
public class Process {

int arrivalTime;
int priority;
LinkedList<Event> events = new LinkedList();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the `events` list. Either initialize it in the `Process` class itself to an empty list or after creating `Process` object.

In Java, if you do not initialize a Class type, it defaults to null.